# Como puedo sumar elementos dentro de un Json

Tags: javascript, nodejs, map

Tengo el siguiente codigo pero no eh conseguido agrupar los valores dentro del Json obtenido.

```
name.reduce(($resultados, name, index) => {
value = registros[0]._id.valor[index];
resultados.push({name, value});
return $resultados;}, []);
const result = {};
for(let {name, value} of resultados) {
if(!result[name]) result[name] = [];
result[name].push({value});}    
return res.status(200).send(result);
```

y obtengo el sig. resultado:

```
{
  'Casi Siempre': [
    { value: 3 }, { value: 3 }
  ],
  'Casi nunca': [
    { value: 1 },
    { value: 3 }
  ],
  'Algunas Veces': [
    { value: 2 }, { value: 2 },
    { value: 2 }, { value: 2 }
  ],}
```

¿Como puedo agrupar los value dentro de cada campo? es decir que queden así:

```
{
  'Casi Siempre': [
    { value: 6}
  ],
  'Casi nunca': [
    { value: 4 }
  ],
  'Algunas Veces': [
    { value: 8 }
  ],}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una vez que ya agrupaste los datos, despues podes hacer un reducer por cada grupo (key).

```
const data = {
  "Casi Siempre": [{ value: 3 }, { value: 3 }],
  "Casi nunca": [{ value: 1 }, { value: 3 }],
  "Algunas Veces": [{ value: 2 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 2 }]
};

Object.keys(data).map(idx => {
  const total = data[idx].reduce((acc, el) => (el.value += acc), 0);
  data[idx] = {
      value: total
  }
});
```

Comment: excelente amigo me funciono muy bien gracias.